# Does SystemVerilog random stability apply to std::randomize()?

Tags: random, system-verilog

Does SystemVerilog random stability apply to `std::randomize()`?

In other words, is it safe to use `std::randomize()` to get deterministic simulation results given a specific seed?

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) mentions the following for Random Stability:

```
Random stability applies to the following:
— The system randomization calls, $urandom() and $urandom_range()
— The object and process random seeding method, srandom()
— The object randomization method, randomize()
```

The above statement mentions `randomize()` in an object context. However, it is unclear whether the same applies to the standalone non-object `std::randomize()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::randomize()` is `randomize()` from the scope of `std`.

[IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.12 *Randomization of scope variables—std::randomize()*

> The scope randomize function behaves exactly the same as a class randomize method, except that it operates on the variables of the current scope instead of class member variables. Arguments to this function specify the variables that are to be assigned random values, i.e., the random variables.

Comment: @Melandru'sSquare it does from the context of the last two sentences of the question. The SO already figured out that random stability applies to `randomize()` and references the IEEE documentation. The core question then becomes the difference between `randomize()` and `std::randomize()`